# Any strategies for locking down Jenkins credentials to a shared-library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I like the use of [Jenkinsfiles](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) and [shared-libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) for their purported benefits, but i have some governance concerns about execution of arbitrary Jenkinsfiles (and potential use of broadly scoped credentials).

I'm thinking it would be convenient to lock down [credentials](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin) to use by a specific shared-library to enforce usage patterns (at the same time, i think it's entirely possible that there are better ways to approach the problem space), so i'm just reaching out for any ideas/guidance in this space.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if our solution would work for you or not.

We have a shared library; reviewed and rather locked down so that not just anyone can make a change to it.  We have that library attached to two separate folders on our Jenkins.

In one folder, our users have their own personal or team based folders and can create jobs and credentials in that space.  There are no shared credentials on this big folder and teams do not share their credentials with each other.

There is a second folder, which none of the users/teams have edit access to, but can execute existing jobs. There are no Jenkinsfile, SCM-based jobs in that folder where they can modify the job via SCM.  This folder has the "locked down" credentials on it that are not meant to be shared or accessible.  The users/teams can edit their jobs (in their folders) to call these jobs - but they can't edit these protected jobs to gain access to the credentials.

It's awkward in a way. But it has preserved the divide between users and credentials they shouldn't have access to.